# Logistic Regression in R with multi level categorical variable

Tags: r, regression, logistic, statistical-significance

After using weight of evidence & Information value mechanism, of the 40 odd   variables I am left with 8 variables which are highly or moderately significant.
One of the independent variable which is categorical has 60+ categories. This is a very highly predictable variable hence please suggest as to how should I
use this variable in the model.
When I add this variable in the model my null deviance and AIC decreases   and makes other predictors loose their predictive power.
Then another model without this variable my null deviance and AIC improves.
What could be the reason. Is this variable collinear with some other predictor.

*Please see the syntax: < Without that Categorical Var>*

```
m1.logit<- glm(survey ~ region+ know + repS+ und+ case_status, family = binomial(logit), data = a1 )
m1.logit  
summary(m1.logit)

Call:  
glm(formula = survey ~ region + know + repS + und + case_status, 
    family = binomial(logit), data = a1)  

Deviance Residuals:   
     ` Min       1Q   Median    3Q     Max`
    -2.579    0.271   0.290   0.336   2.895    

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 2553.5  on 2540  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1287.7  on 2526  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1318    
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 13
```

Also ran an anova test to analyze the table of deviance

```
anova(m1.logit, test="Chisq")   
Analysis of Deviance Table  

Model: binomial, link: logit  
Response: survey  

Terms added sequentially (first to last)  

             Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev             Pr(>Chi)     
 NULL                         2540       2554                           
 region       5       13      2535       2540                0.022 *    
 know         1      507      2534       2033 < 0.0000000000000002 ***  
 repS         1      715      2533       1319 < 0.0000000000000002 ***  
 und          1        3      2532       1316                0.109        
 case_status  6       28      2526       1288             0.000078 ***    

 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Please suggest as to how to deal with this predictor variable with 50+ categories

Comment: Can you please help with what variable it is? how are you using it currently in data: using woe?

Comment: @muni the variable I have is type of support provided to the application for instance - Code development, Single Sign on, API so on and so forth. While creating bins the count of survey received in these categories range from 1 to 1300 cases where 1300 and one another value is an extreme outlier but is very relevant as a large % of the surveys are received in these categories. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create small bins based on event rate and reduce it say 5-10 bins to make it more stable. This will require the bivariate analysis against the target class and also analyzing the proportion of population among different categories. If after binning, some of your predictors become non-significant, you can remove them. You might need to have multiple iterations to come up with final model selection based on your objective.

Comment: This is really a mix of an answer and a request for clarification. This works well on a forum where there is a "to and fro" style of conversation between  questioner and answerer, but not on our "Q&A" style where questions belong at the top, answers at the bottom, and requests for clarification really belong on comments at the bottom of the question. (You'll need more reputation to be able to post comments though.) Take a look at our [tour] to see how our format works.

Comment: I have moved your clarifying questions to be comments.

Comment: I wanted to comment first, but i don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: Thanks @Silverfish so as you suggested as do not have reputation does that mean this question will not be answered here.

Comment: @ShiviBhatia Since this is your own question, you can write comments both under the question and under any answer. I suggest you clarify the points requested by muni.

Comment: @ShiviBhatia, how many exact categories you have in this variable, if it is just about 50 categories, analyse the bivariates against the target for each category. The categories which capture more than normal response, create indicators for them, ignore rest. Also make sure they have good % of population in them

Comment: Thanks @muni. There are exact 66 categories, however as you have suggested i did a bi-variate analysis with count received for each of these categories. Around 89% of the volume is received in only 16 categories hence i believe it would be safe to keep these categories only in the model.

Comment: what is your event rate? you have to see, that these 16 major categories capture major of your target population. If that is not the case, then use only the categories which give you good event rate even though they might be low in population.